# UserDefaults swift as array check if value exists

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

So I'm using:

```
var defaults = UserDefaults.standard
....
seenPosts.insert(CellsData[indexPath.row]["id"] as! Int, at: 0)
```

So I'm basically using UserDefaults to set an array with ids, now I want to check if that array has a value

```
if (self.defaults.data(forKey: "seen_posts").contains(5){
    //do action
}
```

But doesn't work, any tips on how you can check UserDefaults array if it has a specific value in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array(forKey`. `data(forKey` is for `(NS)Data` objects.

You can check for `nil` and if the array contains the value in one expression:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if let seenPosts = defaults.array(forKey: "seen_posts") as? [Int], !seenPosts.contains(5) {
    seenPosts.insert(CellsData[indexPath.row]["id"] as! Int, at: 0)

}
```

Comment: Thank you again, still doesn't work, I have a screenshot here https://screencast.com/t/VEZNNpLGkTP and the error output Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x102bf8d10) to 'NSNumber' (0x102200488).

Comment: That's not my fault. The code above works. You got two issues. 1) It seems that the value for key `id` is a string. 2) to cast a literal string `as! String?` is insane. Do not cast literal strings to anything.